# Getting started with Flipboard

Tags: rss, flipboard

I am a designer for a magazine that would like to explore offering content on Flipboard. I am not really an expert on RSS and I was wondering how I should set up my code? I noticed that on the Flipboard site it gives some examples of optimized feeds, but what does that optimization do?

Ive noticed that some RSS content does not have the same page flipping effect and custom fons that some of the big publishers like National Geographic or Buzz Feed. How do I get that page flip and custom fonts? Does that have something to do with the optimization? or is it just because they are big publishers?